# How to read form-url encoded response

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest

I am making HTTP Post request to Rest service

Content: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I get response in below format

"{\r\n\t\"status\":\"Success\"\r\n}"

Is there any good way to load this string and read status

Comment: Looks like that is in JSON format.  Do a search for parsing JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Json.Net library: http://james.newtonking.com/json (Nuget: Newtonsoft.Json)

You could digest the response into a dynamic class:

```
var testData = "{\r\n\t\"status\":\"Success\"\r\n}";
dynamic testObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(testData);
Console.WriteLine(testObject.status); //Success
Console.ReadKey();
```